# No puedo sumar floats grandes dentro de un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un DataFrame con floats bastante grandes y quiero sumar 1 a algunos de esto números. Ejemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "x": [10**25+0.0],
}
)
print(df["x"][0]+1)
```

El problema está en la siguiente proposición lógica:

```
df["x"][0]==(df["x"][0]+1)
```

que tiene valor `True`. No sé como lidear con esto en lo absoluto. Me imagino que tendría que primero transformar los valores a tipo `int` pero cuando intento esto, casi todos los valores de mi DataFrame resultan ser `-9223372036854775808` (esto último indiferente a si uso `df.astype(int`) o si uso `df.astype(np.int64)`).

¿Como puedo incrementar en una unidad valores grandes tipo `float` de un DataFrame?

Edit: Todos los elementos tipo `float` que tengo en el DataFrame, son números enteros; como en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El float tiene esa limitación. Ya que el número de bits que ocupa un float está prefijado, se balancea el tamaño del número representado con su precisión. Números pequeños tienen mucha precisión. Números grandes tienen precisión muy baja, hasta el punto que se pierde información en las unidades o decenas, y puede acabar con que `x==x+1` sea `True`

La solución sería utilizar enteros en lugar de flotantes, pero ya que pandas se basa en numpy el cual está hecho en C, utiliza un `int` diferente del que utiliza Python.

Los enteros Python son de tamaño arbitrario (algunos ocupan más bits en memoria, otros menos, según su tamaño). Eso no cuadra bien con el esquema de datos de numpy en el que todos los datos son del mismo tamaño para poder vectorizar las operaciones.

Cuando fuerzas `.astype(np.int64)` estás diciendo que use enteros de 64 bits. Esto te permite almacenar números tan grandes como 2**63 (menos uno), pues el espacio de 2**64 combinaciones está dividido entre positivos y negativos. De hecho, debido a la forma en que se codifican los negativos (complemento a 2), si sumas 1 al positivo más grande entrarías en el terreno de los negativos. 2**63 no es suficiente para almacenar 10**25, como puedes comprobar con esta operación (que es fiable porque está usando los enteros python de tamaño arbitrario):

```
>>> 2**63 < 10**25
True
```

Es posible forzar a numpy a que use cualquier tipo de objeto Python (en particular sus enteros grandes), pero la velocidad será entonces penosa. En realidad, basta que quites el `+0.0` para que el dato sea entero en lugar de flotante, y para que sea almacenado por pandas como un entero python:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "x": [10**25],
}
)
print(df)
```

```
                            x
0  10000000000000000000000000
```

Puedes comprobar aquí que la comparación ya sale correcta:

```
>>> df["x"] == df["x"] +1
```

```
0    False
Name: x, dtype: bool
```

Ahora bien, las operaciones con este tipo de datos como ya dije van a ser mucho más lentas que con los datos "nativos" de numpy/pandas. Vas a perder esta ventaja, por lo que cabe plantearse si no vale más no usar pandas y usar en su lugar directamente código Python para iterar por listas.

**Nota adicional**

Es importante que tus valores "de entrada" sean ya de tipo entero. De nada sirve convertir a entero un float grande pues ya será demasiado tarde para hacerlo, y se habrá perdido precisión. Si `10**25` no es representable de forma exacta como flotante (y no lo es, debido a los problemas de precisión que antes expliqué), al convertirlo a entero python recibirás un número distinto del que creías.

Demostración:

```
>>> int(10**25 + 0.0)
10000000000000000905969664
```

Como ves, el resultado tiene un montón de cifras raras al final, en vez de ceros. Esto es debido a que el tipo float, al no poder almacenar de forma exacta un número tan grande, ha almacenado una aproximación que sí sea representable de forma exacta (el por qué de que el 10**25 no sea representable mientras que ese otro número raro terminado en 664 sí lo es, estriba en la representación en base 2 que utiliza por debajo el tipo float)